# Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error after migrating to NgModule, the error doesn't help too much, any advice please?

```
Error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
        at new BaseException (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:5116:27)
        at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13231:35)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13215:48)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:8:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:5555/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:5555/app/main.js "Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues"(anonymous function) @ contracts:142ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?1472711930202:332Zone.run @ zone.js?1472711930202:225(anonymous function) @ zone.js?1472711930202:586ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?1472711930202:365Zone.runTask @ zone.js?1472711930202:265drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?1472711930202:491ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?1472711930202:435
```

app.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { routes } from './app.routes';

    import { provide } from '@angular/core';

    //dgf ng2-translate
    import { TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader, MissingTranslationHandler } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
    import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { TranslationNotFoundHandler } from './shared/common/TranslationNotFoundHandler';
    //dgf ng2-translate END

    import {CalendarModule,DataTableModule,DialogModule,PanelModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

    import {TranslateModule} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

    import { AuthGuard,AppConfigService,AppConfig,DateHelper,ThemeComponent,ToolbarComponent, RemoveHostTagDirective } from './index';
    import { HomeComponent,MessagesExampleComponent,PrimeNgHomeComponent,CalendarComponent,Ng2BootstrapExamplesComponent,DatepickerDemoComponent,UserListComponent,UserEditComponent,ContractListComponent,AboutComponent } from './index';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), /* AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()*/
          FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          //third-party
          ,TranslateModule.forRoot() //,
          //third-party PRIMENG
          ,CalendarModule,DataTableModule,DialogModule,PanelModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,ThemeComponent, ToolbarComponent, RemoveHostTagDirective,
    HomeComponent,MessagesExampleComponent,PrimeNgHomeComponent,CalendarComponent,Ng2BootstrapExamplesComponent,DatepickerDemoComponent,UserListComponent,UserEditComponent,ContractListComponent,AboutComponent
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    provide(TranslateLoader, { //DGF ng2-translate
          useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
          deps: [Http]
      }),
    provide(MissingTranslationHandler, { useClass: TranslationNotFoundHandler }), //DGF ng2-translate

    AuthGuard,AppConfigService,AppConfig,
    DateHelper
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I had this problem when I had two modules both importing each other

Comment: I had the same problem, restarting the editor helped. It was not recognizing newly added files.

Comment: Who else thinks error like these should me more explanatory?

Comment: i got this error because i had an empty entry in the imports array: `, ,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just putting the provider inside the forRoot works: https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), /* AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()*/
          FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          //third-party
          TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
            deps: [Http]
          })
          //third-party PRIMENG
          ,CalendarModule,DataTableModule,DialogModule,PanelModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,ThemeComponent, ToolbarComponent, RemoveHostTagDirective,
    HomeComponent,MessagesExampleComponent,PrimeNgHomeComponent,CalendarComponent,Ng2BootstrapExamplesComponent,DatepickerDemoComponent,UserListComponent,UserEditComponent,ContractListComponent,AboutComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },
    // FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    { provide : MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslationNotFoundHandler},
    AuthGuard,AppConfigService,AppConfig,
    DateHelper
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 237):

For anyone facing this same error, my situation was that I have double commas in the imports section

```
imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpModule,
      FormsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), , // <-- this was the error
      // .... 
],
```

Comment: It was a dot (.) for me

Answer (score 90):

Make sure the modules don't import each other. So, there shouldn't be

In Module A: `imports[ModuleB]`

In Module B: `imports[ModuleA]`

Comment: Sometimes they may reference eachother even though they are used only as a type. In which case import them as a `type` for example: `import type {XYZ} from './xyz'`. Doing this solved my issue.

Answer (score 63):

This can be caused by multiple scenarios like

1. **Missing commas**

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule
   ,routing <= Missing Comma
   ,FeatureComponentsModule
  ],
```

2. **Double Commas**

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
   ,routing <=Double Comma
   ,FeatureComponentsModule
  ],
```

3. **Exporting Nothing from the Module**
4. **Syntax errors**
5. **Typo Errors**
6. **Semicolons inside Objects, Arrays**
7. **Incorrect import Statements**

Comment: Nice summary. Would be great if Angular could throw in some info as of where and in what way module loading fails. As it stands today it is one of the most tedious things to debug. Not sure if I understand the "missing commas" bit, that should compile fine?

Comment: I understand missing commas part- checkout app.module.ts files - imports:, providers:, declarations...etc set of arrays - In the list of string values mentioned, make sure commas are EXTRA or missing... I resolved this by removing extra comma! @Ignatius Andrew... you are GOD! Angular 2/4 is quite quirky!

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem. In my case, the reason is an extra comma.

[image: Code example of extra comma]

Comment: After all the years this still happes... THX

Answer (score 34):

None of the above solutions worked for me, but simply stopping and running "ng serve" again.

Comment: Haha yess, for me too. When you mess around with routing, sometimes Angular needs a restart. The same with moving important core imports or exports between your modules.

Comment: typical problem, in several situations. Angular team should work on that.

Comment: Same for me. Angular should work on this issue.
Wasted my time :/

Comment: For me, it was `circular dependency`

Answer (score 25):

I had this error because I had an `index.ts` file in the root of my app that was exporting my `app.component.ts`.  So I thought I could do the following:

```
import { AppComponent } from './';
```

This worked and gave me no red squiggly lines and even intellisense brings up AppComponent when you start typing it.  But come to find out it was causing this error.  After I changed it to:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

The error went away.

Comment: I think what also works is when you explicitly would write './index'. We had this problem in combination with AoT and ng-packagr.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you should not import a module/component like this:

```
import { YOUR_COMPONENT } from './';
```

But it should be

```
import { YOUR_COMPONENT } from './YOUR_COMPONENT.ts';
```

Comment: Including the .ts!?

Answer (score 8):

I am building a components library and started getting this error in my app that is importing said library. When running `ng build --prod` or `ng serve --aot` in app I would get:

`Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'ɵm in node_modules/<library-name>/<library-name>.d.ts'`

But no errors when using `ng serve` or when testing the modules in the library itself even when building in `--prod`.

Turns out I was misled by intellisense as well. For a few of my modules I had imported a sister module as

`import { DesignModule } from '../../design';`

instead of

`import { DesignModule } from '../../design/design.module';`

It worked in fine in all builds except the one I described.

This was terrible to pin down and I was lucky it didn't take me longer than it did. Hope this help someone.

Comment: That was it xD Do you know by chance how to configure intellisense to not pick the wrong version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.

Answer (score 8):

This issue of circular dependencies of two module

Module 1:import Module 2 
Module 2:import Module 1

Answer (score 7):

Had the same exception when tried to compile an Angular 5 application.

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DemoAppModule'
```

In my case it turned out it was a circular dependency which I found by using a tool [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge). Found the files containing circular dependency by running

```
npx madge --circular --extensions ts src/
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I put the ngrx's `provideMockStore()` into test module's 'imports' and not 'providers' array.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove line `import { provide } from '@angular/core';` from `app.module.ts` as `provide` is deprecated now. You have to use `provide` as below in providers :

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // disableDeprecatedForms(),
    // provideForms(),
    // HTTP_PROVIDERS, //DGF needed for ng2-translate
    // TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, //DGF ng2-translate (not required, but recommended to have 1 unique instance of your service)
    {
        provide : TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    },
    {
        provide : MissingTranslationHandler,
        useClass: TranslationNotFoundHandler
    },

    AuthGuard,AppConfigService,AppConfig,
    DateHelper
  ]
```

Comment: that has sense, I've done it but error is still the same

Answer (score 3):

there is another simple solution for this. I have 2 modules which are somehow deep in the structure using each other. I ran into the same problem with circular dependencies with webpack and angular 2. I simply changed the way of how the one module is declared:

```
....

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        require('../navigation/navigation.module')
    ],
    declarations: COMPONENTS,
    exports: COMPONENTS
})
class DppIncludeModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: DppIncludeModule
        };
    }
}

export = DppIncludeModule;
```

When I now using the imports statement on ngModule attribute I simply use:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ServicesModule.forRoot(),
        NouisliderModule,
        FormsModule,
        ChartModule,
        DppAccordeonModule,
        PipesModule,
        require('../../../unbranded/include/include.module')
    ],
....
```

With this all problems are away.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail how this works? For instance, how do you use the DppIncludeModule in your component?

Comment: Kate, sorry for late answer. I dont use the module in the component, I encapsulate components in modules. Modules are used together. Maybe you have another problem here with the undefined error.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was having an export twice in index.ts

Removing one of them solved the problem.

Comment: holy craps this worked for me!
If you export you module from index.ts & your module imports modules components from same index.ts this seems to cause circular loading.
You should import into your module directly from component file not from index.
TNX

Comment: Trouble shot. Can't imagine how long it will take for me to solve this issue without seeing this answer

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, it is true that the error on the console ain't descriptive. But if you look at the angular-cli output:

You will see a WARNING, pointing to the circular dependency

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
module1 -> module2
module2 -> module1
```

So the solution is to remove one import from one of the Modules.

Comment: What if I require that circular dependency?

Comment: @RuneStar I think you will need to move the dependency to a higher level module and then import the new module on both(X) modules.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are sure you are not doing anything wrong, kindly terminate "ng serve" and restart it. By so doing, the compiler does all of its work and the app serves as expected.
Prior experiences with modules have taught me to either create them when "ng serve" is not running or to restart the terminal once I'm done.

Restarting "ng serve" also works when you're emitting a new component to another component, it's possible the compiler has not recognised your new component, simply restart "ng serve"

This worked for me just a few minutes ago.

Comment: any idea, why its not able to recognise the new component?

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was solved by changing the import sequence :

**One with I got the error :**

```
imports: [ 
 BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule, 
 CommonModule
],
```

**Changed this to :**

```
   imports: [
    BrowserModule, CommonModule, HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

Comment: Unrelated to problem, since BrowserModule exports CommonModule having them both is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there is at least one import for which source file is missing.

For example I got the same error when I was using

```
       import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

But the file './app-routing.module' was not there in given path.

I removed this import and error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, none of above tips didn't help.

In my case, it was caused by WebStorm, combined two imports into one.

```
import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo } from '../component-dir';
```

I extracted this into two separate imports

```
import { ComponentOne } from '../component-dir/component-one.service';
import { ComponentTwo } from '../component-dir/component-two.model';
```

After this it works without error.

Comment: Thanks buddy. That helped

Comment: duplicate of previous answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667611/1243048

Comment: @Maelig I think in the linked answer it was a little bit different problem.
I don't know if it's a typo but there is a problem too with proper dir, one time is `./models` another time it is `./model`

Answer (score 1):

In case your index exports a module - That module should not import its components from the same index, it should import them directly from the components file.

I had this issue, and when I changed from importing the components in the module file using the index to importing them using the direct file, this resolved.

e.g changed:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MainNavComponent } from './index';
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [MainNavComponent],
  declarations: [ MainNavComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ MainNavComponent ]
})
export class MainNavModule {}
```

to:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MainNavComponent } from './MainNavComponent';
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [MainNavComponent],
  declarations: [ MainNavComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ MainNavComponent ]
})
export class MainNavModule {}
```

also remove the now unnecessary exports from you index, e.g:

```
export { MainNavModule } from './MainNavModule';
export { MainNavComponent } from './MainNavComponent';
```

to:

```
export { MainNavModule } from './MainNavModule';
```

Comment: Thanks that was my issue, the IDE imports from folder ex: '/components' my library was being built without a problem but cannot be used in another library

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I added the component in the **index.ts** of a=of the folder and did a export. Still the undefined error was popping. But the IDE pop our any red squiggly lines

Then as suggested changed from

```
import { SearchComponent } from './';
```

to

```
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be some code like this:

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { COMPANY_ROUTES } from 'app/company/company.routing';
import { CompanyService } from 'app/company/services/company.service';
import { CompanyListComponent } from 'app/company/components/company-list/company-list.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
  RouterModule.forChild(COMPANY_ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations: [
  CompanyListComponent
    ],
    providers: [
  CompanyService
    ],
    exports: [
    ]
})
export class CompanyModule { }
```

Because exports is empty array and it has , before it, it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by delete all index export file, include pipe, service. then all file import path is specific path. eg.

`import { AuthService } from './_common/services/auth.service';`

replace

`import { AuthService } from './_common/services';`

besides, don't export default class.

Comment: But how should that help? Removing the file name takes the index.ts of the folder you are assigning.

Comment: @MichaelBaarz at that time, reomve the index file help me resolve the problem. but now, I upgrade ng version to 2.4.9, that problem not exist, that's mean, I can use index.ts file export reference. so I think it's maybe issue with ng build

Comment: At least this is an edge case and results of a bad package structure. Packages should not have round trips. Clarifying the package structure will fix it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBaarz yep, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a misspelled component name inside the `component.ts`.

The import statement didn't show an error but the declaration did, which misled me.

Answer (score 0):

Unused "**private http: Http**" argument in the constructor of **app.component.ts** had caused me the same error and it resolved upon removing the unused argument of the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error will be related to the AppModule.ts file.

To solve this issue check whether every component is declared and every service that we declare is put in the providers etc.

And even if everything seems right in the AppModule file and you still get the error, then stop your running angular instance and restart it once again. That may solve your issue if everything in the module file is correct and if you are still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Solutions above do not worked for me.

So I back the version of angular-cli of 1.6.4 for 1.4.4 and this solved my problem.

I do not know if this is the best solution, but for now, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.
Issue was that I was importing some class  from index.ts

```
    import {className} from '..shared/index'
```

index.ts contain the export statement

```
    export * from './models';
```

I changed it to the .ts file which contain the actual class object

```
    import {className} from '..shared/model'
```

and it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was caused by just unused import:

```
import { NgModule, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Resulting error:

> Input is declared, but it's value never read

Comment it out, and error doesn't occur:

```
import { NgModule/*, Input*/ } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem at the situation:

`- app-module
--- app-routing                                 // app router
----- imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
--- demo-module                                 // sub-module
----- demo-routing
------- imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)] // --> should be RouterModule.forChild!`

because there is only a `root`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just did a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and  *YES* .
And I restart by

```
ionic serve
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after registering new components or registering new modules or after playing around with the routing, angular requires you to restart the development server. I tried all solutions of commas missing or double commas, but my code was perfect without such typos.

So, I just stopped by ng s server and started it again. That resolved the error.